# Can C++ streambuf methods throw exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

I'm trying to find a method to get the number of characters read or written to a stream that is reliable even if there is an error and the read/write ends short.

I was doing something like this:

```
return stream.rdbuf()->sputn(buffer, buffer_size);
```

but if the streambuf implementation of `overflow` is permitted to throw excpections this won't work.  Is it?  I've not been able to find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`basic_streambuf::overflow` is allowed to throw an exception upon failure as documented in *27.6.3.4.5/6*, and sadly there's no way to ensure *compile-time* that the function won't ever throw an exception.

Seems like you are running out of luck and the only way to be 100% sure that `overflow` won't throw an exception is to write your own `streambuf` that just doesn't do that upon failure.

---

> [*27.6.3.4.5/2-3*] **`int_type overflow(int_type = c = traits::eof ())`**
>   ...

> [*27.6.3.4.5/5*]
>
> **Requires**: Every overriding definition of this virtual function shall obey the following constraints:
>
> 1) The effect of consuming a character on the associated output
>   sequence is specified309
>
> 2) Let r be the number of characters in the pending sequence not
>   consumed. If r is non-zero then pbase() and pptr() shall be set so
>   that: pptr() - pbase() 
>   == r and the r characters starting at pbase() are the associated output stream. In case r is zero (all characters of the pending
>   sequence have been consumed) then either pbase() is set to NULL, or
>   pbase() and pptr() are both set to the same NULL non-value.
>
> 3) The function may fail if either appending some character to the
>   associated output stream fails or if it is unable to establish pbase()
>   and pptr() according to the above rules.

> [*27.6.3.4.5/6*]
>
> **Returns**: `traits::eof ()` or **throws an exception if the function fails**

Comment: Unfortunately I'm writing an adapter to convert streambufs to another interface (Microsoft COM `IStream`).  I don't control or implement the streambufs.

Comment: Surely there must be a way to do this though.  Otherwise how would a source stream know how many characters had been consumed by a destination stream if the latter had an error?

Comment: @thehouse the stream operation might fail but you can still call the appropriate functions to get info about the stream. for instance you could compare the value of `gptr` before and after the call that might fail.. or similar, it should work in theory.

Comment: Is that reliable if `sputn`/`sgetn` calls `overflow`\`underflow` part way through.  If the buffer is written out (or there is no buffer at all) `pptr`/`gptr` can be positioned back to the beginning of the buffer or set to `NULL` which would prevent such a calculation.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Also, your quote from the standard seems to imply that `pptr()` is not reliable if the stream operations fails