# Can exceptions in a custom implementation of the std::streambuf be delivered to the stream user?

Tags: c++

Is this a standard enforced behavior that when an exception is thrown
in a custom `std::streambuf` method (eg. `xsgetn`),
it is caught (some status bits are set) but not rethrown ?

Is there any method to alter this (or pass the error message without some
dirty tricks) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can C++ streambuf methods throw exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105657/can-c-streambuf-methods-throw-exceptions)

Comment: I'm quite sure, that catching the exception is not a good idea. Maybe you can alter the behaviour of your stream implementation by using std::basic_ios::exceptions()?

Comment: Nope, it is not a duplicate and the `std::exceptions()` answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general guarantee that things like `operator<<` and
`operator>>` will not raise an exception unless asked to.  You
can ask it to by specifying the exception mask:

```
stream.exceptions( std::ios_base::badbit );
```

(You can specify any or all of the error conditions here, but
`badbit` is probably the only thing you'd ever want to.)

If this is set, and a `streambuf` function exits through an
exception, that exception will be rethrown.

Another possibility is to maintain information concerning the
error in the `streambuf`, with a function to extract it.  Then,
when the client code detects an error, it can use 
`dynamic_cast<MyStreambuf*>( stream.rdbuf() )` to get the
derived streambuf, and call its member functions to get the
error information.