# Visual Studio 2019: Strange behavior in c++ stream implementation

Tags: c++11, exception, visual-c++, streambuf

Consider the following simple streambuf implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class mystreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    int_type underflow() override
    {
        // [27.6.3.4.5/6] ... 'or throws an exception if the function fails'
        throw std::runtime_error("here");
    }
};

int main()
{
    mystreambuf rdbuf;
    std::ostringstream os;
    std::cout << "State: " << os.exceptions() << std::endl;
    try
    {
        os << &rdbuf;
        std::cout << "No except: " << os.good() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error const&)
    {
        std::cout << "With except: " << os.good() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above implementation seems to be following my understanding of other posts:

- [how to set the badbit of a stream by a customized streambuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716688/how-to-set-the-badbit-of-a-stream-by-a-customized-streambuf)
- [Can C++ streambuf methods throw exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105657/can-c-streambuf-methods-throw-exceptions)

However I am seeing different behaviors. With gcc/linux I get:

```
State: 0
No except: 0
```

On Visual Studio 2019 I get:

```
State: 0
With except: 0
```

Which behavior is the correct one ? Both ?

For reference:

- [Can exceptions in a custom implementation of the std::streambuf be delivered to the stream user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380551/can-exceptions-in-a-custom-implementation-of-the-stdstreambuf-be-delivered-to)
- [C++ STL streambuf exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364968/c-stl-streambuf-exception-handling)

Comment: Both behaviors are correct, this is up to streambuf implementation details.

Comment: MSVC seems non-conforming. **[ostream.inserters]/9**, the spec of `ostream::operator<<(streambuf* sb)`, says: "If an exception was thrown while extracting a character, the function sets `failbit` in the error state, and if `failbit` is set in `exceptions()` the caught exception is rethrown." I think it is pretty clearly implied that, if `failbit` is **not** set in `exceptions()`, the exception from `streambuf` should be caught and not rethrown.

Comment: Reported as https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Exception-from-streambuf-should-be-caugh/10555755 thanks !

Answer (score 2):

What you're really supposed to throw in a case like this is an object fo the class `std::ios_base::failure`, or some other class derived from it.

When/if you do that:

```cpp
class mystreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    int_type underflow() override
    {
        throw std::ios_base::failure("here");
    }
};

// remainder as in question
```

...g++ has the same behavior as MS VC++:

```
State: 0
No except: 0
```

It seems pretty clear to me that the real *intent* is that the exception you throw be an instance of `std::ios_base::failure` or a derived class, but it's much less clear whether you're entitled to throw other exceptions and still expect the same behavior. In fact, the only mention I can find out `underflow()` exiting with an error is in a non-normative footnote that reads:

> 279. `underflow` or `uflow` can fail by throwing an exception prematurely. The intention is not only that the calls will not return `eof()` but that they will return “immediately”.

This doesn't provide much indication in either direction. It doesn't specifically restrict the exception to `failure`, but it doesn't specifically say it can be something else. And it's a non-normative footnote, so even if it did say that would only reveal the author's intent, not an actual requirement on the implementation.

Most of the rest of the text deals with what happens if an exception is thrown during execution of an input or output function (in which case, a `sentry` object is created before starting the operation, and there's clear requirements for re-throwing the exception if `badbit` is set).

But your code throws before it ever gets as far as trying to read input from the stream. In that circumstance, it's not clear whether the exception should be re-thrown or not.

#### Summary

It seems pretty clear to me that both VC++ and g++ have sort of an intent that you should normally expect the behavior you're getting from VC++. But I don't see any requirement that you'll actually get that behavior under these circumstances. So I'd say they're both correct, but purely as a quality of implementation issue, VC++'s behavior is probably preferable.

Comment: I cannot get godbolt+msvc to execute the code, but all I can say is that my VS2019 install has a different behavior than yours. `std::ios_base::failure` is being propagated for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has been acknowledged as defect in VS2022:

- https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4322

and fix is at:

- https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/4372